# Add customView in Android ActionBar in right side

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I am new in android and not much aware with customize actionbar.

I want to add one lable in right side of action bar

I have tried multiple solution but none of them work for me

I have tried to add menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Text"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/add_note_count"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

2.In Main App Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I also tried to add custom layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/logout_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Text" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

menu.xml like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_right_button"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Text"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/add_note_count"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
```

I have also tried another solutions but did not get anything

Could you please help me or assist me for same

Help will be really appricates

Thanks

Comment: If you want to show just some text, remove `app:actionLayout`. If you absolutely need to have the action layout, you must add a `OnClickListener` to it yourself and handle the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add `TextView` inside `Toolbar` tag
Use below code format, on your preference you can add required properties

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/optionTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/someText"                
             />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a NoActionBar theme, then add your customized Toolbar:

In order to do this you have to:

Set a NoActionBar Theme in android_manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

Add the Toolbar widget in the activity you want to use it, in my case is activity_main:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/prova"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="someText"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And then you add the toolbar at you activity onCreate with Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
}
```

You must import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar or last code will give build error.

You can get more at https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions